# Changing Tab Item dynamically in UITabBar

Tags: ios, ios9

Is there a way to change the content in UITabBar item dynamically, as it is illustrated in the image. Idea is to indicate the user there are new content he/she hasn't seen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a numbered badge using `UITabBarItem.badgeValue`, but its look won't be configurable.